# Python-AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find';;;

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LIMIT = 50
URL = f"https://au.indeed.com/jobs?q=Python&limit={LIMIT}&radius=50"

def extract_indeed_pages():
  result = requests.get(URL)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
  pagination = soup.find("div", {"class":"pagination"})
  links = pagination.find_all("a")
  pages = []
  for link in links[:-1]:
      pages.append(int(link.string))
  max_page = pages[-1]
  return max_page
def extract_indeed_jobs(last_page):
  jobs = []
  # for page in range(last_page):
  result = requests.get(f"{URL}&start={0*LIMIT}")
  soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
  results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "jobsearch-SerpJobCard"})
  for result in results:
      title = result.find("div", {"class": "title"}).find("a")["title"]
      company = result.find("span", {"class": "company"}).find("a")
      print(company)
  return jobs
```

`.find("a")` above fails with an AttributeError.

I tried to solve this problem but I couldn't solve this
How to solve this problem?

I appreciate any your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are banned as webspider. Control your request access interval or use IP proxy.I tried the following code and it works:

```
URL = f"https://au.indeed.com/jobs?q=Python&limit=50&radius=50"
result = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
pagination = soup.find("div", {"class":"pagination"})
links = pagination.find_all("a")

# results `links`
[<a data-pp="gQAyAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQBlAQEBEgJv9qr6MngKYqAygZcGQXLeIpjmE-ut-bLrnTuy_08iX6xAaszjJSiG-vNnzNmXUIOcTFa_Fd0PU_ic_rQCEjSTbuvMQdt7Ti49I_8KAa8lfxr_tRGneMJS7Zp4j5aAfw4ACgEACyYWJG9VK3o" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=50" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">2</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQBkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQCeAQIBEywKJPFv-46rKuMKdhdcIoQhZpvVGobBWsfDCg1oN9xRgbVFz7mkAm5hhBxrj8VuIZJspoic572EG3CAQcIKIG2fkT-jL8MELkCNEcR6akpBpnooZC-RufYZSbYbFmkkr3gZ3CIQRSMEA_duVyzfsvMxsMK-rqLuPad3TrmnqhXwbXkvqSfrGtpf2kGrdrkJC0-65ga-tm4Z9j8ACgEACyYWJG9VK3o" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=100" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">3</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQCWAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQDPAQQBEygMLAcaBwM3W3uwbgJhfcm37VGf7CA-V9s7C8WiDibhpdyHvsWdu7Z0enc4lpxNynDBXLOV1J0mcU38fDjUlg6LVVtgDYHc3kzJE6eyoWle7m8KQ12uPgEmrGJSZEJvBJwm6RyiFt5zqbbyGjxQboWU2UsOcaPWHPUkEqAU8FzK9IdpZsbxaQcESPag4XumTLO4G9F-n5AvhbjSm_Aoap_uBLD3LfUHxdDgRbB_5xRt7X_4eaMXWAoNae8vXLzeRdRgbcYY30juEg4zAAoBAAsmFiRvVSt6" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=150" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">4</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQDIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQDxAQMBJVYWTAYHgbR3MwAn_XH9h2ZRK42SJPHtz3G2yZdv2GQ8Nz6tfCDD7TucD03gcekM4ddRvpVomR_JXdzdD1CeRUo5TpEYvPVIkGYLhb_zvmC0HkZt6wyJb5YwX2EY-eQEGEW4nk3BWJO6b1jqqH9_G94EmkXh8_JElzoPXeXBxU7yPFgrjlpYhYQsI3ewOkMtjDzXyNxQMdSQNwCIRz8W3q30s9cmf4KapXS0VVs684Zkp-LL98qVu0mpPjZFUWoSoxsn6BmHCSKT7R5AjRC5-oguMvTbGXLRa0bp2xoNMSi35AesozfTl3nmzVjqjQAKAQALJhYkb1Ureg" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=200" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">5</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQD6AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQEGAQQBKlYWUAYwCR2csQSI513OzupO8ULJehMJWtLMOPr3qGCTwKZZPkN9oJoOb_Zp0gAA9jKbVECP4Eew_OJsXAMbIISzN2mm8ZXBz3D3ERyNdMejyeZ3mvmrjRilg1eNME1C920j756vjC_jd_5rn1kOanemFHZh9Kp4LbvfiBd3Egu7LPM-lRfo-BXPq4ZSJO9_CXXLBkUh_cdvuV55WGA6e6-M9sTGy_vscJamaSH9fuE8vhj5VH2KZNiJQNYvDPt4SB5ooKGviIpGqI0fm5aaMxSwc5QphnbMl3GdYKp0ojAIlC1ySbpwTPaUbedMRKwbNasl3snj9APtSPEhw5b-ilKC7wAKAQALJhYkb1Ureg" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=250" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">6</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQEsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQEjAQUBQYQBBxYINA4kBgODBuVz5GpF7hXlPMT0j92WTnyO0s8wLNJXX9wM30N3idA2JTTNx1NX-0tJTZNqQ1Gb8sYCSxOTbQC6kiJRtDeQThWsqNOLYcLFeRuJqjxD5aTwvlLBAaqDhpDO2Q7kChhs_TTrB4fHFIc_LsHXygLYd0p1nIAIf6Evxd96wDFNKUqCLOw1MFV27aEJBfjh0XMOwLD0fnrDVKBPnY1zTPqevTm9F-Lq7xATs97LgQTDnWekpxFKIxEBgjv8Tnz8VOz0ctRRyKpibqs7jqR_KuPLE_yknG6fG9o2nk27Q_vy_WyqvYHdcjQjf4BzDHD9Ol-AqvQ4OK6UPNLiT8ktNEM9_1TztGGisEsLZj0EBhQKxzIfVmtSAAoBAAsmFiRvVSt6" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=300" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">7</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQFeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQE1AQUBQYQBBxYINA4kBgH7hS669J7bY7R-HQQOdIRQehUvWI0MuI1h5sxVpWCYqSEenEgMMg3YgloT2BOiR9DwfzUUCIGlorFqlBxVSbhincy2BGZemFifEIWVVnBZOk27rbPtKYZ0SVimLoUDYX1-ZtYsJ24ur6zpjt529zUnKs8_krbtd-HeQwtGC5fCtZj16TIuXy4uHHNKNf7sgMsYM-FOfIa6sDsAh6vcxv23ZMXpVPU4V-M2NfNHDb5Z94-6lcN5ehavFtdGCJNQasec4BItcwqSG1ejKz5QMOPwMhx8Yq4qPiYxtajZI2UJipQ753sRDzAKWQpF2fsIZ74PdmHamxDHd01fedjlYaazrFHYudQHBpnMp9a5GXPahNtXByOrvNXDiAriJuAIULfeIaS5FWuuAAoBAAsmFiRvVSt6" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=350" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">8</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQGQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQFKAQYBQYQBCBYINBEkBoQBBgfk0Kc_rIXrAmGuUl37ZM6m9s2lDU6YQIMZf2K5i0XhnLKS7013cCcyOOXwQSdQql0qW6kwK9VjQ7_STSqtdxawvz4v2oT0F7Deky7XBFp0lfe0dmgu6aVwNoQZwlOD2U-vfuepuKm0rQTxAsO9Z7AQ-ihpt8vvzo5DxvmaKGOPaSLkTeVxTZtfws48MWlEHrIsJDD3mz-_Fi5mZwDtGMNZ9pFdjZ0DVTWG68NfQTGKVFBcJJN4F-5o2mZl4535eEr8KEUduqIQl5cZA_qOsGQJC6Ih1NYS0ngpzjcLeKbQWuEVvwRSXq3du0SW-NRfytpqV6xFrTL_FdLrNWtr5c4TPzWduotnI6KzEJTIzjGeoQl2wr6h3id6bimqV4o5RHnagXbCPbpR2tojH_H793ELFsfnP0aTs5-AAAoBAAsmFiRvVSt6" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=400" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">9</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQHCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQFKAQUBSpoBCDAaTgdgBhP9t0hic68OWadeoOG71bjkTkZbddzqyVE0L0LPHpSgzeToUy2iLAFPBKUacdtajsk-4dY6a2Ev-jKC4VQadh5I-u0MWCcJ-gzQ-1L8kkaTz6toLbClDm1Cfbe8qb0JL_4MSPwh7B0m2hzH2ZUdum-vg6qLdm1TdnWXNyic83ZwVP5C_HYNVAQTletSk5fCLaEy3hfAbbGP_3QWRvwLyekY9hXlD9tF5EHEGlU4aDF1VKiCT8ENNqo_1UtTCg9JVZE_4jMddV-e4JURqosYe8kRWhHlI9qITcLjw7i2WREgzzmYAj9d6K4z6VzoNddyCN--hwv3DLK05aYFUPVYNsbJA1Fbw3mP75ugITiO2OYxvsFmGLV6dqz9Kxh7Xnc4nrrfj1ISVWgGlvxLL7My--OGGyccmUdqL1I-3SJZAAoBAAsmFiRvVSt6" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=450" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">10</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQH0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQFGAQUBTJoBCBwHEBxSCCr2i77XyY5aNrU2gUYIm7CaYxJ4N9Zhw3DzzZXt62nV9HP0VSFkBXKOScvxpjYCrdHyqNPSSS0lSLTXrncNptC2Er3uWwFrwMdT7mRqTB8NgIQNSE9u77QF1hYOMrW6EKBiTRqzsfx3TEel-mG2QVW0TLaOq2CvEgkUoOPLoZpRKY4uysQXH3e2Sipd3Xas-T7xAQu5B5MsOK6tp6Ncou2dUIyIHqbhy8KhT5s3s-aDNEZ526WDlKDOY8NrU8nepgRPDtJDELw6pj_rZcCKnAIxlvet2ymnQqi3d67yZdk5LM9AyTx6NlBsqo582w4ITHjF8mTKXgStITV1UmCg76hojwOIukqirsqnuSgx-6GYW0l3q0Fm8Y6TAuWUyvsBvLZT6bTAqquCT86grSPQ6M8_RbNwH3gwCK8ACgEACyYWJG9VK3o" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=500" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">11</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQImAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQFOAQgBTKYBBxAGEAwaCRQGJAiYAQYBMpTn2gWioaW5TJ_8tf8UBb-ApTFKCKHM9gLcpEvWcsOg6Ffy-3LbUDsI3Bq5odflvz8tR32Xi7W3H7fplksEEbFMA_aHIJO_OVfmxqSY0eVaLN4pWRoEjly7b2hBr2S-FiJxN7OVmMdYORuSGqBrDVWSmOreTH8VSwBs4qzdDDcZqBixs7Og9j8Iy4y0mKFG0rr7KKnQp6qKJX00XnFa-HRQ7ed7NVZeowPCnOnf0YFRWzIuuaknNgZv_sU5xXpIW2tO6JihX8DC2VFAoi8MpBJ-SnpWqKdbIcRpYWEfOEqijxLvItr2bDB_GEIWJ-NJ3XCsogKfr2EtqgZb9q3aY-hby57-aCULey3JtZeKyt1Oe71hZluZFEaoxgNBTN7PBD-fUzuuUD1HkVWmuCgdy_c0NvVHj6kMIgAKAQALJhYkb1Ureg" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=550" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">12</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQJYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQFGAQgBTKYBBxAGEAweBxAGJAiYAQknjUfF56CZJ9_cmOJM_dwF56uYRKym0E2kifeqpdwoaAYLiGFq_wxssYvy7eiGHSLt5Zt2e4vyDVC_AaKueAE6Ct30h04fn_VZKhGf1nevrskSPfqzclWyjNIQhezgroPHVDZg9vBKvZjcI1PBqx-WvrorddPqYyYZtVDw3xa_m_p3usCAmt8ip4KtnAiWQOsctirDeSsnymlsbx5CTYAtVStXQbOj8IcE8qDKV2p6xjVR5xzSoxJ_C6thACn_OksI7hUdZ57c27S9K4Uos1Y-RpISHDDT5g9txjpLI1pCfH-Ro6wHTFQKTwrMHMRs8C_c8saBLkiys8wIUzx2upw_BNiCCRLNoNEiRRs3GFse1VzvKq8pioz6OjUlytVOB8Yf7CeemX1emBQ8cvXBWXKpxOcACgEACyYWJG9VK3o" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=600" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">13</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQKKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQE9AQgBQYQBCiIHEAYQCh4HEAYiBgDNmPRdG3CZS0Y_ZFUwS4kMxnhzm8uQEvjGJhqPJZxOLl0luGdlwlwIYbeYE59NPqkApNSN7FYl6trzTY_hJQh8QhXqYx-ltLZc2kg0UU5zNgX0-4mC3xnhCj_yHYFKn7yKslxAFRNbO6reEJZljCVyhxhPW_MUEhrs8x52z0nsVf_BAGpkayK0nMF-Cnx8jrshWdPLBQAWPom5nvn4WOvdPkj6U2xSL117ak8W0_kx9ETlHKVJwlEdWNRgm6f1RoDn9-t8q_hp2Y1AuSL8rppdlYeorEqCasIuJ_CBAeyj446GJIahVirvMEg-L5WOe-kCrv2uDwugoDY1PBKJnmE2lL9FrIr_EakXoOwElzKOk6BnkgIeHfn9uOhnsYL6GaqjWtRoQwk1hKsACgEACyYWJG9VK3o" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=650" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">14</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQK8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQE1AQYBQYgBCC4GFAcqBsQBBgFaj40Gm5ksWqmENRXhqxvkswGJVTEMsT5m0O6Ju-7aPcuOBBFEYPkRGPyPbnPOiK5IOkcmKP7FRtbc-EwZl-jNr4-EUsXT6hYdt5YXfPVIWwI7hzfmEbdTqwe4nBvpguFzdZg_7obKjBfPeDnPIOG8El5Eqo-wSeQqN5WQzZNY-3H8e3cgapPjjDlKVWECMwqs8GTwVCTIpVCMeSaGF8Xt1D-9xch2_LhAJ0vQn9lcP8AqS0Z_COwnlYhOfxpFB4a-A5up6BOP1FiBU8VfipXG1cj-MZInQVnfFqiHmbfPnYQAtrlwSF9bhHLyfsczM0F5AAs8J2UYIAY3dUSfqPlbTuwNP12MrZ--T8qHM5a8TJyQxa5-4gxD3u-mRkfTjR5f_Dn4AAoBAAsmFiRvVSt6" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=700" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">15</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQLuAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQENAQUBKFIYNggSChoGBEwHRqWL1U0AV2pZPjVsueymPrTQM-IpLNjGm0t0jiasWGXgNROuUrstRJEncfkDBa4S0Hp2jH5fQ07Eh04uloIGX-9Iv9AK8esY-2MjBCWm1WPMUEhPxP5wnBzSQ387j0p5d_IBXpD5gmnGFiyhAxRbr7x-hqeG9v4eQv8W8zrLgM9HmXxjyiIzAkixMUjlx604R4h9tDplYkecGuM3XIP1sM_C3vwRXegLuvRC3nG6Js2Nr8_O8IBqH-rPnOCvOlo_4h3d2Nm9GE8MMW0jYuhRP2ZioDsJb1UQMKZrV8pymU5z15o0CxVXgu9RDnYorG7f7H3xQWUeLstyzIgxulwACgEACyYWJG9VK3o" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=750" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">16</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQMgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQDqAQIBKHYGAhtDFQlvnw58Fpv5zB3tk3_NZ_hXKnFxqTgsZDUInpgw2OBmTXh-C3N8lpad3aVfuXhHHEQVg03V97zxHn_fgzDW8b_FduIvGzeepsGu-NbgFY5-1QgVZ43ldco8hZGkNw814GsD06WMsNURgKpxpqfQMdoiwD2ArnHrbsiVzFjh-i2HB8DDuiqg3TTHWDktfnjfiNOwrwptIlH5oJ7Zk0ctc2c4i7Y6CtzGJgKAvU4CzcFgyRRKYMQm9QtRpGful_exD_i8qH6t5qEkzMQwwDRai2S35N9UZ7eIDpUa2l4jeFtUAAoBAAsmFiRvVSt6" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=800" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">17</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQNSAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQDCAQEBKBq8I6lhGETjqQKmwzqWcBrqvYTMrgKK2jFIv0n_l2O84us36fmMdiFpcc7E3lqkOAzVQqSpdLmQfUnkF5WcHHbtyVdtwYLJ8Y6iR9qBP3wgCnoui7_YIZri7NfgqLliZ_7c2B6JRRrCou5risyuXCoPtx1gbxDFAMRK5r1j4YXYY3n12wkg0swi-0NPkzezGISRh9VtKdAtMNFL2X-xavg_oGxK7SZZWCD_yFFa3My8ALVL_A_UrOlHpW1_kfQACgEACyYWJG9VK3o" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=850" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">18</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQOEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQCbAQIBGDIIAsaKT2_m3rQyDfm9oHjeATREPC7pwr0D1U5OqU1fVyAf0HSUPjqYeUQo7fOVMfrd-3OVBYyAYWi49AFqBQ-2KleAaAxEuqmj3iRsADLML7D2dBJmOxGqJy2qDOjDJWuWzxg70G2jcUaJq1F6FlZ8bsP9JxZg4L-Bxd4DsavGJc7P6CnOokkjCyH_Ph5bwQxRe2d6GHAACgEACyYWJG9VK3o" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=900" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">19</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQO2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQBgAQEBEQYvcl7zvgpjNDm2XduH24nEQi6R7dDz8xwPwd9LZqDiHkh39bBDWqN_gh99amMMGOosS-sF4gxpXuh-TQwlb4k1MZysY9yit8N6kPMcuaM9txfSaR1u3gv4F83nAAoBAAsmFiRvVSt6" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=950" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn">20</span></a>,
 <a data-pp="gQAyAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABdifSFQBlAQEBEgJv9qr6MngKYqAygZcGQXLeIpjmE-ut-bLrnTuy_08iX6xAaszjJSiG-vNnzNmXUIOcTFa_Fd0PU_ic_rQCEjSTbuvMQdt7Ti49I_8KAa8lfxr_tRGneMJS7Zp4j5aAfw4ACgEACyYWJG9VK3o" href="/jobs?q=Python&amp;limit=50&amp;radius=50&amp;start=50" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);"><span class="pn"><span class="np">Next »</span></span></a>]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because

```
result.find("div", {"class": "title"})
```

didn't find div with title class and it returned None, you code is trying to find substring on None data i.e empty data.

Try out following code, to make is more robust apply same operation on company variable as well

```
  for result in results:
      title = result.find("div", {"class": "title"})
      if title is not None:
          title = title.find("a")["title"]
      company = result.find("span", {"class": "company"}).find("a")
      print(company)
```